# Tint a particular color in XNA

Tags: windows-phone-7, xna

I have a popup texture which has a white outline and I would like the white outline to change color according to the current theme.

Unfortunately, calling `SpriteBatch.Draw()` with the tint I want tints all non-transparent pixels, while what I want is to only tint (in this case), white pixels.

Comment: check this
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3255311/color-replacement-in-xna-c-sharp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I ended up doing it this way, even though it's not that efficient. Thankfully I do it only once and during the LoadContent().

```
texture = content.Load<Texture2D>("popup");
Color[] colors = new Color[texture.Width * texture.Height];
texture.GetData(colors);
for (int i = 0; i < colors.Length; i++)
{
    if (colors[i] == Color.White)
    {
        colors[i] = PhoneTheme.Current.PhoneAccentColor;
    }
}
texture.SetData(colors);
```

Comment: Maybe you should use white color for those accent zones and then tint the whole texture with the phone's accent color, right with the `spriteBatch.Draw(t2d, rect, color)` method?

Comment: As i said, the `spriteBatch.Draw(t2d, rect, color)` tints also the non-white pixels, which gives an unwanted effect.

Comment: I meant separating the texture into two textures, one is never tinted, and you tint the other one.

Comment: Oh, it looks like [there is an answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15530531/1306322) suggesting the exact same thing I had in mind.

Answer (score 2):

How about using two textures; one that contains only the white border (all other pixels are transparent), and one that contains the popup texture. Then you can just apply the tint to the border texture using `SpriteBatch.Draw(borderTex,borderTex.Bounds,tintColor)`, and perform an additional `SpriteBatch.Draw(tex,tex.Bounds,Color.White)` to blit the popup texture on top of the result. The advantage of this is that your draw operation is not CPU bound (like the solution you posted) as SpriteBatch can utilize your [GraphicsDevice](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.graphics.graphicsdevice.aspx) (GPU).

Comment: I'm kind of on a tight budget when it comes to adding more textures, but I'll keep this in mind just in case thanks.